# transitionDelay on makeStayles on material-UI

Tags: material-ui, makestyles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  buttonStyle: {
    background: "red",

    "&:hover": {
      transitionDelay: '1',
      transform: "scale(1.1)",
      background: "red",
    },
  },
});
```

> how can i implemated i  transitionDelay on  makeStyles? This did not
> work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a few things here:

1. You need a `transitionProperty` to which the `transitionDelay` will apply to. In your case, it is the `transform` CSS property.
2. Your `transitionDelay` needs to include the units of the delay e.g. `1s` or `1000ms`.
3. If you want to apply your transitions on the button when it is not on a hover state, then apply the styling to the button instead of the `&:hover`.

This is what it will look like:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  buttonStyle: {
    background: "red",
    transitionProperty: "transform",
    transitionDelay: "1s",
    
    "&:hover": {
      transform: "scale(1.1)",
      background: "red",
    },
  },
});
```